# Which is the appropriate preposition: "at" or "on"?

Tags: prepositions

> The detector is placed **at** the center of the brick.

or

> The detector is placed **on** the center of the brick.

If I mean to say the detector is placed on top of the brick but at its center, which one of these sentences is correct? Or are both wrong?

I think 'at' would be wrong because it's on its surface, not inside the brick, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "The detector is placed on the brick *in* the center."  
Probably this?

Comment: "on" probably makes most sense in this case, but if you said "at" or "in" it might be obvious you can't physically inside the brick, and so people would assume you mean "at" or "in" the center of the top surface of the brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On" is better because it implies on top. If you say "At the center of the brick" there is the possibility for me to think you drilled into the brick to put the detector inside. Of course, if the context of the sentence discredits this possibility, then either one is fine.